# MOSS2007 active DBs

Tags: 2007, administration, database

Whats the best way to tell which dbs are being used in your farm? Having moved and changed db servers over time, i now have dbs everywhere, wanting to do a clean up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To really see if a Content Database is being used you will need to check the Site Collections within in it. Within the SPSite object there is a property called SPSite.LastContentModifiedDate which you could then write out as part of Rob's code above and use that to work out which Content Databases / Site Collections can be archived.

The code would be something like this:-

```
  foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
  {
      foreach (SPContentDatabase contentDb in webApp.ContentDatabases)
      {        
          Console.WriteLine("Database Name: " + contentDb.Name);
          Console.WriteLine("Database Server: " + contentDb.Server);

          SPSiteCollection siteCollection = contentDb.Sites;
          foreach(SPSite site in siteCollection)
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Site: {0} {1} Last Modified: {2}", site.RootWeb.Name, site.Url, site.LastContentModifiedDate.ToString()));
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Regards
Simon

Comment: Just because content hasn't been modified is not an indicator of whether or not it is "in use"...it could be a publishing site collection that has not had any updates in a while...it could be an archive...etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the content DBS associated with each web app in central admin:  http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/blog-moss/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=65

You could also write some code to enumerate the web app in you farm and the content DBS within them:

```
foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
{
    foreach (SPContentDatabase contentDb in webApp.ContentDatabases)
    {
        if (contentDb.Status != SPObjectStatus.Disabled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Database Name: " + contentDb.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Database Server: " + contentDb.Server);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also download the [StoragePoint BLOBulator](http://www.storagepoint.com/product.aspx?tab=7). I wrote it when I was part of the StoragePoint team and while it was not built for this use, it will enumerate all the web apps int the farm and then you can expand the web apps to see the content databases under them. Note, it will only give you the names, it won't tell you what DB server they are on.